# Why (int)==(float) always compiles to (float)==(float)

Tags: c#, .net, cil, system.reflection

I'm researching C# compilers and trying to understand the math operation rules.

I found a incomprehensible behavior with `==` operator between two different primitive types.

```
int a = 1;
float b = 1.0f;        
Console.WriteLine(a == b);
```

This actually compiles to

```
.locals init (
    [0] int32,
    [1] float32
)

IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldc.i4.1
IL_0002: stloc.0
IL_0003: ldc.r4 1
IL_0008: stloc.1
IL_0009: ldloc.0
IL_000a: conv.r4
IL_000b: ldloc.1
IL_000c: ceq
```

which means

```
(float)a == (float)b
```

My expectation was `(int)a == (int)b` because left value is an `integer`.

Any reasons for this result?

---

- Here's my guess: `int->float` is faster than `float->int`

Comment: When both are converted to `float`, `0 != 0.4`. If both were converted to int, `0 == 0.4` (since the non-Integer part of the float would be discarded), right? Indeed if both were converted to `int`, any value between `0` (inclusive) and `1` (exclusive) would be considered equal to 0.

Comment: There is no implicit conversion `float` to `int`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is really nothing to do with *speed* (as you suggest) and more to do with *Implicit Conversions*, you can find the relevant information defined under the topic of *Numeric Promotions* in the [C# Specifications](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf)

> **12.4.7 Numeric promotions**
>
> *Numeric promotion* consists of **automatically performing certain
>   *implicit conversions* of the *operands* of the predefined *unary* and
>   *binary* numeric *operators***. *Numeric promotion* is not a distinct
>   mechanism, but rather an effect of applying *overload resolution* to the
>   predefined *operators*. *Numeric promotion* specifically does not affect
>   evaluation of user-defined *operators*, although user-defined *operators*
>   can be implemented to exhibit similar effects.
>
> As an example of *numeric promotion*, consider the predefined
>   implementations of the binary * *operator*:
>
> ```
> int operator *(int x, int y);
> uint operator *(uint x, uint y);
> long operator *(long x, long y);
> ulong operator *(ulong x, ulong y);
> float operator *(float x, float y);
> double operator *(double x, double y);
> decimal operator *(decimal x, decimal y);
> ```
>
> When *overload resolution* rules (§12.6.4) are applied to this set of *operators*, **the effect is to select the first of the *operators* for
>   which *implicit conversions* exist from the *operand* types.**

Further More

> Binary *numeric promotion* occurs for the operands of the predefined `+`,
>   `–`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `&`, `|`, `^`, `==`, `!=`, `>`, `<`, `>=`, and `<=` binary operators.
>   Binary numeric promotion implicitly converts both operands to a common
>   type which, in case of the non-relational operators, also becomes the
>   result type of the operation. Binary numeric promotion consists of
>   applying the following rules, in the order they appear here:
>
> - If either operand is of type decimal, the other operand is converted to type decimal, or a bindingtime error occurs if the other operand is
>     of type float or double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type double, the other operand is converted to type double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other operand is converted to type float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type ulong, the other operand is converted to type ulong, or a binding-time error occurs if the other
>     operand is of type sbyte, short, int, or long.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other operand is converted to type long.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type uint and the other operand is of type sbyte, short, or int, both operands are converted to type
>     long.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type uint, the other operand is converted to type uint.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

You can get a feel for this with the examples they show

```
byte b = 1;
short a = 2;
WriteLine((int)b==(int)s); // promotes both to int

int i = 1;
double d = 2;
WriteLine((double)i==d); // promotes i to double
```

Or your example

```
int a = 1;
float b = 1.0f; 
WriteLine((float)a==b); // promotes a to float
```